# Asymptotic expansion for reciprocal of Bessel function

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series, bessel-functions

The asymptotic expansion for the Bessel function $J_n(x)$ with integer $n$ is known and given at https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17. Is there a way to find the asymptotic expansion for $1/J_n(x)$? I'm not sure how given the expansion for $J_n(x)$ is not a pure power series.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at this paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/937/1/012047/pdf

Comment: Why are you interested in the asymptotics of the reciprocal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is problematic to take the reciprocal of the standard compound asymptotic expansion of $J_\nu (z)$. Instead, we can use the following representation in terms of [the modulus and phase functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.18):
$$
J_\nu  (z) = M_\nu  (z)\cos (\theta _\nu  (z)) = \sqrt {\frac{2}{{\pi z\,\theta '_\nu  (z)}}} \cos (\theta _\nu  (z)).
$$
Then, if $J_\nu(z)\neq 0$,
$$
\frac{1}{{J_\nu  (z)}} = \sqrt {\frac{{\pi z\,\theta '_\nu  (z)}}{2}} \sec (\theta _\nu  (z)).
$$
The phase function and its derivative possess the [asymptotic expansions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.18.E18)
$$
\theta _\nu  (z) \sim z - \left( {\tfrac{1}{2}\nu  + \tfrac{1}{4}} \right)\pi  + \frac{{4\nu ^2  - 1}}{{2(4z)}} + \frac{{(4\nu ^2  - 1)(4\nu ^2  - 25)}}{{6(4z)^3 }} +  \ldots 
$$
and
$$
z\,\theta '_\nu  (z) \sim z - \frac{{(4\nu ^2  - 1)}}{{2 (4z) }} - \frac{{(4\nu ^2  - 1)(4\nu ^2  - 25)}}{{2(4z)^3 }} +  \ldots ,
$$
as $z\to\infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$, provided $\nu=o(z)$.